# java Mail Search Term does not work foe message Number Term

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

Message Number Term is not part of Search Term in IMAP Search Sequence class. How to do fetch limited number of messaged from IMAP Folder get Sorted Messages().

Comment: Well, you could issue a command along the times of "dear server, please search for messages numbered 123, 124 or 125", the server would answer "the search result is 123 124 125" and then you could retrieve those messages. But in this case, you don't really need to ask the server. You know the answer.

Comment: The message number search term is just the message numbers.  If you're trying to filter down, you can do something like `UID SEARCH 10:20 UNSEEN`